# aws cli list snapshot modify output

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I am using the following command to display snaptshots.

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters "Name=volume-id,Values=vol-035a45c00af749577" --query 'Snapshots[*].{ID: SnapshotId,StartTime: StartTime,Key:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]}' --output text
```

The output of the command is as follows:

```
KEY     WebServices
snap-0905735cc7d8543b6  2021-12-07T03:37:21.532000+00:00
KEY     WebServices
snap-007ab931e25f43136  2021-12-06T03:41:11.753000+00:00
KEY     WebServices
snap-000d71e3b1b1bb929  2021-12-08T03:31:10.383000+00:00
KEY     WebServices
```

I need to set up an exit similar to this.

```
KEY     WebServices
snap-0ba6345e8c19e697b  2021-12-09T03:29:40.251000+00:00
snap-0905735cc7d8543b6  2021-12-07T03:37:21.532000+00:00
snap-007ab931e25f43136  2021-12-06T03:41:11.753000+00:00
snap-000d71e3b1b1bb929  2021-12-08T03:31:10.383000+00:00
```

I’m not an advanced user of sed, could someone help me do it?
Regards,

Comment: Can you not use CSV output type? I know it's not output but wondering if you really need as pure text.

Comment: Append `| awk 'NR>1 && $1=="KEY"{next}1'`?

Comment: The issue is that you are requesting a 1-to-many output of Snapshot to Tags. Try telling it to output only one tag with `Key:Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[] | [0]` (or something like that).